# keyboard selection for custom dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have made a custom jquery dropdown plugin which is seems to be working good on desktop and mobile.

However,on mobile we are using native html behavior and in desktop we are designing the dropdown as we need with the help of ul li and then appending it to the select tag.

But i am not able to make any selection from keyboard which we normally can from the default native dropdown. Is there any solution ?
could someone help me how should i do it with keyCode or is there any solution ?

```js
alphaDropdown: function(){
       (function(jQuery){
          jQuery.fn.AlphaDropdown = function( configurations ){
        
            var defaultConfigurations = {
              disabledFirst: false
            };
        
            var extendedconfigurations = jQuery.extend(defaultConfigurations, configurations || {});
        
            function setBackData( ){
              jQuery('.selectr-desktop-custom').each(function(){
                var selectedValue = jQuery(this).removeClass('active').find('select').eq(0).val();
                var selectedIndex = jQuery(this).removeClass('active').find('select').eq(0)[0].selectedIndex;
                if( !selectedValue || selectedValue == ""){
                    var dropdown = jQuery(this).find('select').eq(0)[0];
                    var _index = dropdown.selectedIndex;
                    if( _index >= 0 ){
                        selectedValue = dropdown.options[_index].innerText;
                        selectedIndex = _index;
                    }
                }
                if ( selectedIndex != -1 ) {
                  var moveBy = -(selectedIndex * 40), movewithY = 'translateY('+moveBy+'px)';
                  jQuery(this).find('ul').eq(0).css({
                    transform: movewithY
                  });
                };        
              });
            }
            
            jQuery(this).each(function(){
                if( jQuery(this).parents('.selectr-desktop-custom').length > 0 ){
                    jQuery(this).parents('.selectr-desktop-custom').children('ul').remove();
                    jQuery(this).unwrap('.selectr-desktop-custom');
                }
                var preselectedvalue = jQuery(this).val() ;
                if( !preselectedvalue || preselectedvalue == ""){
                    var dropdown = jQuery(this).eq(0)[0];
                    var _index = dropdown.selectedIndex;
                    if( _index >= 0 ){
                        preselectedvalue = dropdown.options[_index].innerText;
                    }
                }
                var list = "<ul>"
                jQuery(this).wrap("<div class='selectr-desktop-custom' tabindex='0'></div>");        
                jQuery(this).find('option').each(function(){
                  var currentValue = jQuery(this).val() && jQuery(this).val().trim() != ""?jQuery(this).val():jQuery(this).text();
                  if( jQuery(this).index() == 0 ){
                    if( extendedconfigurations.disabledFirst && currentValue == preselectedvalue ){
                      list += "<li class='disabled active drop' alpha-value='" + currentValue +"'>" + jQuery(this).text() + "</li>"; 
                    }else if( extendedconfigurations.disabledFirst && currentValue != preselectedvalue ){
                      list += "<li class='disabled drop' alpha-value='" + currentValue+"'>" + jQuery(this).text() + "</li>";
                    }else if( !extendedconfigurations.disabledFirst && currentValue == preselectedvalue ){
                      list += "<li class='active' alpha-value='" + currentValue +"'>" + jQuery(this).text() + "</li>"; 
                    }
                    else{
                      list += "<li alpha-value='" + currentValue +"'>" + jQuery(this).text() + "</li>"; 
                    }
                  }
                  else{
                    if( currentValue == preselectedvalue ){
                      list += "<li class='active' alpha-value='"+  currentValue +"'>"+ jQuery(this).text() +"</li>";
                    }else{
                      list += "<li alpha-value='"+  currentValue +"'>"+ jQuery(this).text() +"</li>";
                    }                    
                  }
                });        
                list += "</ul>";        
                jQuery(this).before(list);

                jQuery(this).parents('.selectr-desktop-custom').click(function(e){
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    jQuery('.selectr-desktop-custom').removeClass('active');
                    jQuery(this).addClass('active'); 
                    jQuery(this).find('ul').eq(0).css('transform','translateY(0)'); 
                }).find('ul').eq(0).find('li').click(function(e){
                    var _index = jQuery(this).index();
                    var moveBy = -(_index * 40), movewithY = 'translateY('+moveBy+'px)';
                    var ul = jQuery(this).parent();
                    var dropdown = ul.parent().find('select').eq(0);
                    jQuery(this).parent().css({
                        transform: movewithY
                    });
                    var seletedValue = jQuery(this).attr('alpha-value') || null;
                    if( seletedValue ){
                       dropdown.val(seletedValue).find('option').each(function(){
                            if( jQuery(this).text() === seletedValue || jQuery(this).val() === seletedValue ){
                                jQuery(this).attr('selected','selected');
                            }else{
                                jQuery(this).attr('selected',null);
                            }
                        });
                        dropdown[0].selectedIndex = _index;
                        dropdown.trigger('change');
                    }                    
                    jQuery(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active').closest('.selectr-desktop-custom').removeClass('active');
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    return false;
                });
                jQuery('body').click(function(e){
                    setBackData();
                });
            });
            setBackData();
            return this;
          }
        })($);
      }
```

Comment: So, there are a number of custom dropdown plugins.  Have you examined, say, jQuery UI's "selectmenu" plugin to see how they handle keyboard events?

Comment: Thankyou @James
actually we were having a UX of dropdown.
We have to make that as per that so thats why i switched to make it as custom dropdown.
so is there any solution in my code that i can manipulate and achieve what i want

Comment: Yeah but it will require you understand keyboard events and the effect you want when they happen.  That's why I suggest a very similar custom dropdown to study.  [Link to the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widgets/selectmenu.js)

Comment: Thank you @James if i go for the link you provided i will have to change my custom code and it will take time.
i have worked on keyboard events earlier but for now am bit confused to do with keyboard keyCodes so thats why i need help for that